# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /data/filer-6/web/web1670/htdocs/donation/index.php on line 219

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I could not figure out how to use the if statement to this. I try to show the latest 5 five donators and what they bought.

```
                    $con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
                    // Check connection
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                    }

                    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM commands ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;");

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                      echo $row['playername'] . " " . if($row['packageid'] == 1) {
                        echo "Donator Tier 1"};
                            elseif($row['packageid'] == 2) {
                                echo "Donator Tier 2"};
                                    else {
                                        echo "Donator Tier 3"};
                      echo "<br>";
                    }

                    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: doesnt matter, it has errors everywhere.

Comment: You can't use `if` in the middle of an expression. This isn't ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code after I've purged the syntax errors and indentation:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['playername'] . " ";

    if($row['packageid'] == 1)
        echo "Donator Tier 1";
    elseif ($row['packageid'] == 2)
        echo "Donator Tier 2";
    else
        echo "Donator Tier 3";

    echo "<br>";
}
```

When you're doing some more complex logic, it is worth it to print it in multiple echos, rather than trying to squeeze it in single statement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an `if` statement (or blocks like `{ ... }`) inside an `echo` statement. You could use a ternary expression like:

```
echo (condition) ? "some string when true" : "some string when false";
```

and use that in concatenation, but as you are using multiple if / else statements, that would not be very readable.

Comment: thats true - but if-elseif-else with ternary will be incredibly unwieldy.

Comment: @MightyPork I agree, that's why I said that in my last sentence :-)